# bdl_pos_adj: set IRQ timing workaround for hda-intel

Tags: kernel, logs, audio, kernel-modules

I get following errors in my logs:

```
kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: IRQ timing workaround is 
        activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj
```

Google found some old posts [here](http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2013-05/msg10784.html) and [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11398) which deal with the same problem. The offered solution suggests to change the value for the kernel module:

```
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1 bdl_pos_adj=1,48
```

Howeveer, nowhere is there explained what the numbers mean. Moreover, the current (default) value that I have now has multiple numbers:

```
# cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/bdl_pos_adj
-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
```

Can somebody please explain what all these numbers mean, and how to change them to get rid of the errors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel documentation describes `bdl_pos_adj` as follows (see [the ALSA driver configuration guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/alsa-configuration.html#module-snd-hda-intel) and [More Notes on HD-Audio Driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/notes.html)):

> `bdl_pos_adj` - Specifies the DMA IRQ timing delay in samples.
> Passing -1 will make the driver to choose the appropriate
> value based on the controller chip.

(sic). On Intel controllers, the default is 1 (which is what you can see in your own `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/bdl_pos_adj`). The multiple numbers are there because the module supports multiple HDA devices (eight by default, it's `SNDRV_CARDS` in [the kernel source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13.7/source/include/sound/core.h#L22)). I'm not sure off-hand what the correspondence is; I'd have hoped it would match the card number, but you're getting the error for card #0 while your `bdl_pos_adj` suggests it's taking its value in second position...

As far as fixing the problem, there isn't much documentation and the code doesn't say much either. The only suggestion I have is to follow the instructions, and try increasing the value until you get something that works:

```
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1 bdl_pos_adj=2,2
```

(I'm using `2,2` here because I'm not sure which of the first two will be used for your device.)

Comment: shall I keep the `enable_msi=1` as in the example, or is it irrelevant here ?

Comment: If you didn't have it already then drop it, just keep the `bdl_pos_adj` option.

Comment: OK, using `-1,2` did not make any difference, but eventually increasing up until `-1,64` seems to have fixed the problem. Could there be any negative consequences due to the number being too high ?

Comment: and is it really necessary to keep it power of 2 (as the linked post suggests) ?

Comment: Looking at [the controller code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/pci/hda/hda_controller.c#L328) (where `bdl_pos_adj` is used), I don't see why it should be a power of two. As far as negative consequences, all you risk is skipping to much in an audio buffer (as I understand it)...

Comment: In my case too small bdl_pos_adj=2,2 keep crackling, too big as bdl_pos_adj=48,48 make skips. So bdl_pos_adj=16,16 sounds good.