# Delayed audio driver in Debian 8 for several minutes

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

After a reboot, audio will not work for quite some time.  After some minutes, I'll hear my speakers pop, then I know sound will work again.  I have Pulseaudio and Alsa installed.  Why would this be delayed and how could I fix it?

```
$ aptitude search pulseaudio alsa jack| grep ^i
i A alsa-base                       - dummy package to ease purging of obsolete 
i   alsa-firmware-loaders           - ALSA software loaders for specific hardwar
i   alsa-oss                        - ALSA wrapper for OSS applications         
i   alsa-tools                      - Console based ALSA utilities for specific 
i   alsa-tools-gui                  - GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hard
i A alsa-utils                      - Utilities for configuring and using ALSA  
i   alsamixergui                    - graphical soundcard mixer for ALSA soundca
i   alsaplayer-common               - audio player (common files)               
i   alsaplayer-gtk                  - alsaplayer gtk interface                  
i   alsaplayer-jack                 - alsaplayer output module for JACK         
i   alsaplayer-oss                  - alsaplayer output module for OSS          
i A gstreamer0.10-alsa              - GStreamer plugin for ALSA                 
i   gstreamer1.0-alsa               - GStreamer plugin for ALSA                 
i   libalsaplayer0                  - alsaplayer plugin library                 
iBA libjack-jackd2-0                - JACK Audio Connection Kit (libraries)     
i   libjack-jackd2-dev              - JACK Audio Connection Kit (development fil
i A libjackrabbit-java              - content repository implementation (JCR API
i A libsox-fmt-alsa                 - SoX alsa format I/O library               
i   pulseaudio                      - PulseAudio sound server                   
i A pulseaudio-module-x11           - X11 module for PulseAudio sound server    
i A pulseaudio-utils                - Command line tools for the PulseAudio soun
i   python-alsaaudio                - Alsa bindings for Python        

$ sudo lspci | grep [Aa]udio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

I'm using the standard 1/4th inch audio jack, not any HDMI audio

Comment: i _think_ it's pulseaudio specific, because i have vlc set to output module Pulseaudio, and if i launch vlc it will hang without displaying a gui until audio "_kicks in_".

Comment: Remove alsa-oss

Comment: no change afterward.

Comment: speakers pop about 4m 40s after boot or xfce login. (indicating sound driver enabled)

Comment: Login, immediately kill pulseaudio (`ps axu`, `kill`), use `aplay -L` and `aplay -D plughw:... some_file.wav` to test if it works. This tests if it's Pulseaudio specific. Also look into `syslog` for error messages, or messages indicating what happens 5mins after boot/login.

Comment: Yes, I can kill pulseaudio and play via alsa, immediately after reboot/login.  Is pulseaudio even recommended/required.  Is there a defacto fix, or should i consider purging pulseaudio altogether.  I'm also wondering if the HDMI audio (which I don't use) is getting in the way.

Comment: kernel: [ 1075.762318] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #1. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.

Answer (score 0):

create/modify `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as per [bdl_pos_adj: set IRQ timing workaround for hda-intel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203792/bdl-pos-adj-set-irq-timing-workaround-for-hda-intel)

`options snd-hda-intel enable=1,1 bdl_pos_adj=-1,32`

actual `bdl_pos_adj` values may not be correct, but it worked for me.